# How can I send an audio from url using bot.sendAudio()

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telepot

I have a telegram bot that you can text a YouTube link and it replys with a link that you can open to download the audio format. I wanted to make it more efficient and instead of sending a link (using bot.sendMessage()) that you can click to download, How can I make the bot send the audio it self from the link using bot.sendAudio()? ... Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Chris and welcome to SO! I would like to advise you some SO documentation that may help you in asking a better qestion. For instance you may be interested about the [topics we discuss here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [the way to ask a 'good' question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the way to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you find it useful, you can still edit your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use URL string instead of file in [sendAudio](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendaudio) method.

Note that you can send max 20MB of content.

Comment: what kind of URLs? should it end with .mp3